# Laravel Omnipay Authorize.net SIM Method Merchant ID Issue

Tags: authorize.net, omnipay

I'm Trying to implement omnipay authorize.net using SIM method but I encountered this issue:

> The merchant login ID or password is invalid or the account is inactive.

I already set the `apiloginId` from my sandbox authorize.net account. I also tried to use the `apiloginId` to a static page with authorize SIM sample codes and it was successful. any help? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message is a bit of a catch-all when generated by Authorize.Net I have seen it in all these circumstances:

- The authentication token has not been generated or used correctly.
- The account is not set up properly, such as not registering the callback URL (x_relay_url) in the admin pages.
- The callback uses SSL but with a self-signed certificate. Authorize.Net does not like self-signed certificates, but is happy enough with non-SSL callback URLs.